# Input string not in correct format exception c#

Tags: c#

I have read data from a text file. I want to change data in that file into an Int array. I don't know why it wrong.

```
class Program
{
    public static int[,] provincial = new int[100, 100];

    public static void loadProvincial()
    {
        string[] s = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Lyn203\\Desktop\\data\\final-graph.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
        {

            string[] splitedArray = s[i].Replace("\t","_").Split('_');

            //Console.WriteLine(splitedArray[i]);

            for (int j = 0; j < splitedArray.Length-1; ++j)
            {

                provincial[i,j] = int.Parse(splitedArray[j].ToString());
            }

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        loadProvincial();

    }
}
```

and TextFile:
http://textuploader.com/djhbe

Comment: Which line is throwing that exception?

Comment: What is the value of `splitedArray[j].ToString()` when that exception occurs?

Comment: Check if the value is empty or not like !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(splitedArray[j]) or int.TryParse then assign to array

Comment: This occurs on int.Parse().  It's because `splitedArray[j].ToString()` is not an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to call the [overload of Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) that removes the empty entries. In other words, if you have two consecutive tabs without a value between the two tabs your result will contain an empty string. That string is not convertible by Int32.Parse

```
string[] splitedArray = s[i].Replace("\t","_")
                            .Split(new char[] {'_'}, 
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Instead if you want to add a zero when your code meets an empty string then replace the Int32.Parse with Int32.TryParse. This will allow you to check the result of the conversion without getting an exception in case of a missing value

```
 for(.....)
 {
     int value;
     Int32.TryParse(splitedArray[j], out value);
     // if conversion fails, value will be set to the default value for integers (0)
     provincial[i,j] = value;
 }
```